# Is there a Haskell idiom for trying several functions and stop as soon as one succeeds?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell, patterns-and-practices

In Haskell, I can use the type `a -> Maybe b` to model a function that either returns a value of type `b`, or returns nothing (it fails).

If I have types `a1, ..., a(n+1)` and functions `f1, ..., fn`, with `fi :: ai -> Maybe a(i+1)` for all `i`, `1 <= i <= n`, I can chain the functions by using the `>>=` operator of the `Maybe` monad and write:

```
f1 x >>= f2 >>= f3 >>=... >>= fn
```

The `>>=` operator ensures that each function is applied as long as its predecessor has returned a meaningful value. As soon as a function in the chain fails, the whole chain fails (returns `Nothing`) and further functions in the chain are not evaluated.

I have a somewhat similar pattern in which I want to try several functions on the same input, and return as soon as one function *succeeds*. If all functions fail (return `Nothing`), the whole computation should fail. More precisely, I have functions `f1, ..., fn :: a -> Maybe b` and I define the function

```
tryFunctions :: [a -> Maybe b] -> a -> Maybe b
tryFunctions []       _ = Nothing
tryFunctions (f : fs) x = case f x of
                            Nothing    -> tryFunctions fs x
                            r@(Just _) -> r
```

In a sense this is dual to the `Maybe` monad in that a computation stops at the first success instead of at the first failure.

Of course, I can use the function I have written above but I was wondering if there is a better, well-established and idiomatic way of expressing this pattern in Haskell.

Comment: Not Haskell, but in C#, you'll occasionally see the null-coalesce operator (??) used like that: `return f1 ?? f2 ?? f3 ?? DefaultValue;`

Comment: Yes it does - this is `Alternative` which is the symbol infix operator `<|>` and is defined in terms of a Monoid

Answer (score 8):

Given a closed set (fixed number of elements) `S` with elements `{a..z}` and a binary operator `*`:

There is a single identity element `i` such that:

`forall x in S: i * x = x = x * i`

The operator is associative such that:

`forall a, b, c in S: a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c`

You have a monoid.

Now given any monoid you can define a binary function `f` as:

```
f(i, x) = x
f(x, _) = x
```

What this means is that for the example of the `Maybe` monoid (`Nothing` is the identity element denoted above as `i`):

```
f(Nothing, Just 5) = Just 5
f(Just 5, Nothing) = Just 5
f(Just 5, Just 10) = Just 5
f(Nothing, f(Nothing, Just 5)) = Just 5
f(Nothing, f(Just 5, Nothing)) = Just 5
```

Surprisingly, I can't find this precise function in the default libraries, which is likely due to my own inexperience. If anyone else can volunteer this, I would sincerely appreciate it.

Here's the implementation I deduced off hand from the above example:

```
(<||>) :: (Monoid a, Eq a) => a -> a -> a
x <||> y
     | x == mempty = y
     | True = x
```

Example:

```
λ> [] <||> [1,2] <||> [3,4]
[1,2]
λ> Just "foo" <||> Nothing <||> Just "bar"
Just "foo"
λ> Nothing <||> Just "foo" <||> Just "bar"
Just "foo"
λ>
```

Then if you want to use a list of functions as input...

```
tryFunctions x funcs = foldl1 (<||>) $ map ($ x) funcs
```

example:

```
instance Monoid Bool where
         mempty = False
         mconcat = or
         mappend = (||)

λ> tryFunctions 8 [odd, even]
True
λ> tryFunctions 8 [odd, odd]
False
λ> tryFunctions 8 [odd, odd, even]
True
λ>
```

Comment: I do not understand why `<|>` treats the identity of a monoid in a special way. Couldn't one pick an arbitrary element of an arbitrary set to play that special role? Why does the set have to be a monoid and the special element wrt `<|>` its identity?

Comment: @Giorgio perhaps that's why `<|>` doesn't rely on monoid and I have this all mixed up? It relies on `Alternative` typeclass. To be certain - I'm looking at my own answer and realizing it's not quite right as `[1,2] <|> [3]` gives the unexpected `[1,2,3]` so everything about using the monoid type class to identify an identity is right - and the other key is associativity *is* necessary to get the expected behaviour, perhaps `Alternative` doesn't give the behaviour I thought off hand...

Comment: @JimmyHoffa it will depend on the typclass Maybe <|> will be different to List <|> no ?

Comment: @Giorgio look at my last 2 examples of `f` to see why associativity is a necessity.

Comment: i.e. monoid for lists is the empty list and concat

Comment: @jk in a list the typically expected monoid is list under concatenation, where `[]` is the identity element - therefore the behaviour the poster wants would involve the first non `[]` to be the return value

Comment: @JimmyHoffa The reason `Applicative` is a superclass of `Alternative`, afaik, is to allow `Alternative` to supply the `some` and `many` methods (whose [laws](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) require `<*>` and `pure`).

Comment: yep so you will need to do some sort of fold applying <|> at each stage which is I beleive what Thomas' answer does

Comment: @Giorgio edited my answer - have another look, though it relies on `Eq` as well as `Monoid` - I really feel like I'm missing something where `Monoid` should give the ability to succeed fast by simple function application rather than requiring the extra `Eq`, but can't think of it off hand. Also there really probably is an implementation in the standard libraries, I just don't know of it off hand.. Alternative works for `Maybe` and, but it's functionality is unclear to me as it appears to do more after success for `[]` and other types

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: Thanks a lot for your answer (+1). I will review monoids during the coming days and then take a close look at your examples.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: I am reading about monoids in http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#monoids The `First a` type seems what I am looking for. Then I could use `mconcat` in that monoid to defined `tryFunctions`. `tryFunctions fs x = mconcat [First (f x) | f <- fs]`. Maybe this can work.

Answer (score 6):

```
import Data.Monoid

tryFunctions :: a -> [a -> Maybe b] -> Maybe b
tryFunctions x = getFirst . mconcat . map (First . ($ x))
```

Comment: This is clean and simple but fixed to `Maybe`... My solution is constrained by `Eq`, somehow I feel like we're both missing something available by way of `Monoid` generally...

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: Do you mean you would like to generalize this solution so that it can work with other data types, e.g. `either`?

Comment: @Giorgio exactly. I wish the only constraint could be `Monoid` so that anything with an identity element could have a set of 2 functions (I think this is a type of binary field), where one of the functions chooses identity over all others, and the other function always chooses the non-identity element. I just don't know how to do this without an `Eq` to know which value is `identity` or not though.. obviously in additive or multiplicative monoids you get the ladder function by default (always choose non-identity elements using the monoids binary function)

Comment: `foldMap` can be used in place of `mconcat . map`

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a lot like [replacing failure by a list of successes](https://rkrishnan.org/files/wadler-1985.pdf)

You're talking about `Maybe a` rather than `[a]`, but in fact they're very similar: we can think of `Maybe a` as being like `[a]`, except it can contain at most one element (ie. `Nothing ~= []` and `Just x ~= [x]`).

In the case of lists, your `tryFunctions` would be very simple: apply all of the functions to the given argument then concatenate all of the results together. `concatMap` will do this nicely:

```
tryFunctions :: [a -> [b]] -> a -> [b]
tryFunctions fs x = concatMap ($ x) fs
```

In this way, we can see that the `<|>` operator for `Maybe` acts like concatenation for 'lists with at most one element'.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of Conal, break it into smaller simpler operations.

In this case, `asum` from `Data.Foldable` does the main part.

```
tryFunction fs x = asum (map ($ x) fs)
```

Alternatively, a la Jimmy Hoffa's reply you can use the `Monoid` instance for `(->)` but then you need a `Monoid` instance for `Maybe` and the standard one doesn't do what you want.  You want `First` from `Data.Monoid`.

```
tryFunction = fmap getFirst . fold . map (fmap First)
```

(Or `mconcat` for an older, more specialized version of `fold`.)

Comment: Interesting solutions (+1). I find the first more intuitive.